# RSS feed for software updated

Tags: html, rss, packaging, microformats

Is there a standardized type of RSS feed or some microformat where you can announce updates to software you are distributing via your own website?

Comment: There is also Sparkle's XML format: https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/blob/master/Sample%20Appcast.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hatom is the microformat for syndication, which can be polled to announce your updates. super easy, html classes http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom

Comment: Thanks, this still looks like the standard solution.